# Manipulate canvas background color in Raphael by using variable paper

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I want to set the background color to a specific color. I use the following code:

```
//JavaScript Code
var paper = Raphael(200, 350, 320, 200);
paper.attr("fill", "#f00");
```

Somehow, this code doesn't work. Please help, how can I set the background color of paper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the answer below for a better way, but you can make a rectangle that fills the whole canvas area:

```
var paper = Raphael(200, 350, 320, 200);
var rect = paper.rect(0, 0, 320, 200);
rect.attr("fill", "#f00");
rect.attr("stroke", "#f00");
```

Answer (score 26):

Actually, it is entirely possible to set the background color for an SVG canvas -- the caveat here is that, though Raphael controls all of the elements inside the canvas, it offers very little stylistic control directly over the canvas itself.

Fortunately, you can get access to the dom node associated with a Raphael paper object through its *canvas* property.  That makes it easy to do things like this:

```
var paper = Raphael(200, 350, 320, 200);
paper.canvas.style.backgroundColor = '#F00';
```

Better yet, you could define your canvas background/border/padding as part of your application's stylesheet, and then just make sure the canvas is set to use the appropriate style:

```
var paper = Raphael(200, 350, 320, 200);
paper.canvas.className += ' my_svg_class';
```

Comment: +1 both work perfectly in VML mode as well as SVG (on both IE8 and IE7). **http://jsbin.com/uYilUqe/2/edit** Strangely, the  `.className` method doesn't work for me in up-to-date Chrome or Firefox (or IE9 and IE10), but does work in IE7 and IE8. I've never seen something work in old IE but not in standard browsers before...

Comment: @user568458 I had the same problem, but apparently it can be worked around in the modern browsers by also setting the ``baseVal`` field: ``paper.canvas.className.baseVal += "my_svg_class"``